# Printing LaTeX command without compiling it

Tags: verbatim

How could I write a command in LaTeX, so after compiling it will be shown as a text in `PDF` and not executed?

For Example, I would write `\it This is how you write in italic` and the compiled `pdf` would contain the exact same text between the quotation marks without `\it` being executed.

Comment: You can use the `verbatim` environment if you have a lot of text or you can use `\verb|\it|`.

Comment: `\verb+\it+` and NO!!!!! you do NOT use `\it` to get *italic*!!! Please to not teach this to users. Use `\textit{...}` or if it is for emphasizing `\emph{...}`. `\it` is `TeX` and should not be used in LaTeX

Comment: `\itshape` is also acceptable as a switch.

Comment: Sorry, I don't usually use \it, it was just the first thing that came to my mind when I was thinking about a simple example

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can put them in the `verbatim` environment.

```
\begin{verbatim}
\it This is how you write in italic
\end{verbatim}
```

P.S. If you need to put them in-line, you can put them in the `\verb==` environment:

```
\verb=\it This is how you write in italic=
```

Comment: @Sigur According to [here](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~peterseb/tex/samples/verbatim-environment.html): the verbatim environment is supported directly by LaTeX but by loading the verbatim package one gets a better implementation.

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain how the command works (as opposed to how it works with `=` and `=` as delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

`showexpl` package that loads `listings` package might be interesting for you as it provides more sophisticated features as follows.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand*{\noaccsupp}[1]{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showexpl}


\lstdefinestyle{Common}
{   
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=1em,
    numberstyle=\tiny\noaccsupp,
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,
    tabsize=2,
    columns=flexible,
    includerangemarker=false,
    rangeprefix=//\ ,
}


\lstdefinestyle{A}
{
    style=Common,
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bf,
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    commentstyle=\color{green}
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\section*{lstinline}
\lstinline[style=A]|\LaTeX\ is fun.|

\section*{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=A]
\LaTeX\ is also fun in displayed mode.
\end{lstlisting}

\section*{LTXexample}
\LTXexample[style=A]
\LaTeX\ is fun.
\endLTXexample
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accomplish this inside a section title, it doesn't work with `\verb|\it|` AFAIK. However, instead, you could use `\textbackslash it\ { \ }`. to get `\it{}` printed.

Answer (score 0):

The [ltxdoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxdoc) document class, which is used for `LaTeX` documentation, contains the following definition:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\cs[1]{\texttt{\char`\\#1}}
```

With this definition you can use `\cs{textit}` and the output will contain `\textit`.

Comment: With this command is difficulty to produce `\textit{}`. Compare `\cs{textit{}}` and `\cs{textit\{\}}` with `\verb|\textit{}|`

Comment: @Sigur `ltxdoc` provides also macros `\marg` and `\oarg` for mandatory and optional arguments. You'd write something like `\cs{textit}\marg{italic text}`

Comment: i've got a macro in my `faq.sty` that allows me to say `\cmdinvoke{providecommand}[n]{command def}`  (and a variety of things involving `*`s and the like.  recommended only for readers with a tex-like stomach...  `http://mirror.ctan.org/help/uk-tex-faq/faq.sty`